# In a desktop-first CSS approach, do browsers start 'drawing/rendering' the pixels before @media queries?

Tags: css

I know mobile-first is more efficient due to various reasons, one of them being less CSS over-rides.

But I want to ask a more granular question. Say a web site is created with desktop-first approach, then when I view it on a mobile, does the mobile browser start 'drawing/rendering' the styling right when it starts reading the CSS file and then re-draws the 'rendering layers' once it reaches the @media queries below?

Comment: Browsers parse the CSS files in one go and apply those styles to HTML tags present when they are done parsing all CSS files (otherwise you see a flash of unstyled content). They don't parse the CSS line by line each frame and then draw the desktop variant and after that process the media queries. It's not like that.

Comment: @Dai wth? I am not asking what YOU prefer. Just answer the question if you know it or pass on.

Comment: @PeterKrebs thanks. I asked this question because I read that `transform` property is more efficient than `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` or `margin`, so in a desktop-first approach if I declare margin in the default css and then in a `@media` query change this margin, so will all the 3 layers: layout, paint and composite layers be re-rendered?

Comment: I believe the browser will do all three in one go no matter what. No need to draw pixels if there's more rules to loop through. The media queries are a conditional expression that would be evaluated each time but it will not cause redrawing or anything. I also don't think you will have a measurable difference in a real-world scenario.

Answer (score -1):

yes , browser start read css file code , at line 1 code and keeping going to read all codes in your css file  .

```
    1 - body {}
2 - p {color:red}

3- @media screen and (max-width:758px) {
p {color:green}
 }
```

*read for more detail if you want*

brwoser read first line 1 code then 2 , then 3 ,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

brwoser first watch html code then parse html code ,

you can see this svg image for how browser process

[svg image process browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_works/rendering.svg)

if you are use link css or cdn or javascript browser jump into the links ,

browser read codes up to down .

if you have this link in html like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

browser first read main.css then style.css

But if you use inline css in html code because the browser reads the full html first, the browser sees your inline css so this css is very important to the browser! And the browser ignores external or inline css, only reads inline css

Comment: _"browser first watch html code then parse html code"_ - Please elaborate on this - especially what you mean by "watch HTML"...

Comment: I'm afraid this answer doesn't make any sense to me. At what point does the system start rendering the actual output?

Comment: i put one linke for you you are see this linke ?  this link for mdn refreance  

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_works/rendering.svg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).